# Creating a Universal Objective-C framework, LIPO can't map input file

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, lipo, ios-universal-framework

Been researching this for the past day without success, hopefully someone can provide a few pointers on this.

I have inherited an old objC static library project which I'm trying to convert to a dynamic, universal framework.

Created a new target for the framework, compiles w/o issue (after a few build setting tweaks)
Created a new aggregate, added a Run Script Phase:

```
    ######################
    # Options
    ######################

    REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER=true

    FRAMEWORK_NAME="MyUniversalFramework"

    SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

    DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"

    UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal"

    FRAMEWORK="${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework"


    ######################
    # Build Frameworks
    ######################

    xcodebuild -project ${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcodeproj -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

    xcodebuild -project ${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcodeproj -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

    ######################
    # Create directory for universal
    ######################

    rm -rf "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

    mkdir "${UNIVERSAL_LIBRARY_DIR}"

    mkdir "${FRAMEWORK}"


    ######################
    # Copy files Framework
    ######################
    cp -R "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${FRAMEWORK}"

    cp -R "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${FRAMEWORK}"


    ######################
    # Make an universal binary
    ######################

    lipo -create "${SIMULATOR_LIBRARY_PATH}" "${DEVICE_LIBRARY_PATH}"  -output "${FRAMEWORK}" | echo

    ######################
    # On Release, copy the result to release directory
    ######################
    OUTPUT_DIR="${PROJECT_DIR}/Output/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}-${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneuniversal/"

    rm -rf "$OUTPUT_DIR"
    mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_DIR"

    cp -r "${FRAMEWORK}" "$OUTPUT_DIR"

    if [ ${REVEAL_ARCHIVE_IN_FINDER} = true ]; then
    open "${OUTPUT_DIR}/"
    fi
```

When I try to produce the framework I get the error:

```
    Showing Recent Messages
    fatal error: lipo: can't map input file: /Users/dhomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyUniversalFramework-dzrstgkuullfwqdlupoeqbqzapxz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyUniversalFramework.framework (Invalid argument)
```

The .framework IS created, and importing it into a client project allows to compile for device, but simulator throws "Framework not found error"

I have done these frameworks in the past but only w/swift code, Any help/pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Same problem now

Comment: Any solution on this ?

Comment: Hi David, you can check this tool as an alternative: https://www.github.com/gurhub/surmagic Best

Answer (score 7):

You can't lipo the framework, you need to lipo the inside, should be "MyUniversalFramework.framework/MyUniversalFramework"

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I want to tell @david-homes you can check this tutorial https://medium.com/@hassanahmedkhan/a-noobs-guide-to-creating-a-fat-library-for-ios-bafe8452b84b